# continuously moves on full page js

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, fullpage.js

I am using [Full Page js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) .

When I mouse wheel up or down once it take me to next section clearly but when I move mouse wheel more than once continuously then my page also moves continuously which I dont want.

I want like [this](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) page.I want if mouse wheel is moved continuously on a section then it should move just one slide/section.

I checked it's documentation but there is no attribute to stop that while in the above example link it is working fine.

How can i do this ?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something wrong as you are showing the demo page of the plugin which acts like you want. Without any code it will be difficult to help you here. Add a link to your site or the code you are using (html + js)